# Replacing a washing machine: can I disconnect wasting hose from inside the machine?

Tags: washing-machine

My setup is an absolute joke, I have no access to where the drain hose enters the wall. I can only disconnect this hose from the machine, and use the same hose on the new machine.

Can I somehow open my machine, disconnect the hose, open the new machine, and plug the old hose into it?

Comment: Probably, but without any detail we cannot say for sure. You have the old and new pipes - check.

Comment: In my experience the "wasting" hose ( I'd call it drain hose) attaches to a barbed fitting on the *outside* of the washing machine. How about a picture of the entry of the drain hose on your machine?

Comment: You'd probably be better off splicing the hose on the new machine onto the old hose. You would get a short tube that both hoses would slip over. Such a splice tube may be commercially available since sometimes the drain hose is not long enough and an extension must be added to the hose.